# What is the machine pictured in this David Letterman transition?

Tags: david-letterman-show

I was watching old David Letterman segments. In [an episode from 1982](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-8DMdfl53g4), I believe, the transition to a commercial break showed this image ([5:17 in the video](https://youtu.be/-8DMdfl53g4?t=314)), which I'm assuming is of some sort of film-related utility room:

[image]

For some reason, I'm fascinated by this image. My question is, what is that machine (and bonus, what/where is that room)? If it helps, assuming it's an image of a room in the studios somewhere, Letterman's show was shot at 30 Rockefeller in NYC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an old movie theater projector.  You can see the housing for the movie reels on the top and bottom, which match this video at around the 54 second mark: